# Dynamic formControlName in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I got a modal form inside a **loop** with menus.

```
<div  *ngFor="let menu of menus let i = index">
...

                    <form #updateMenu="ngForm" [formGroup]="nameForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(updateMenu)" style=" padding: 20px; display:flex; justify-content:center; flex-direction: column;" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                            <mat-label>Title</mat-label>
                            <input matInput placeholder="{{menu.title}}" formControlName="title" [(ngModel)]="menu.title" required>
                        </mat-form-field>
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                            <mat-label>Description</mat-label>
                            <textarea matInput name="description" formControlName="description" placeholder="example: All of our pizzas are amazing" required></textarea>
                        </mat-form-field>
                            <br>
                        <label>Image of menu *</label>  
                        <img src="{{url + 'menu/get-image/' + menu.image}}" style="height:150x;" />
                    <input type="file" name="image" (change)="onSelectedFile($event)" required/>
                        <br>
                        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="SEND"
                        [disabled]="!updateMenu.form.valid" style="border:none; background:#181818; height: 40px; color: #f1f1f1; font-size: 22px;" />
                    </form>
</div>
```

I have a problem with `formControlName` and it is that when using `[(ngModel)]` it always loads the values of the last element of the for loop

I have tried to make it like `formControlName` to make it dynamic but I get an error:

> TS2339: Property 'title' does not exist on type 'MenuupdateComponent'

My component with formBuilder:

```
public nameForm:FormGroup;

  constructor(private _AdminmenuService:AdminmenuService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.nameForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      title: '',
      description: '',
      image: ''
    });
   }
```

How can I fix that? Thank you so much!

Comment: show more code. The error is not related to the part that you've shown. Also, what is `menu` in your component template?

Answer (score 0):

There are two available solutions:

1. Do not merge [reactive form](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) with [template driven form](https://angular.io/guide/forms)
2. use [form array](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray) to build iterated form

Comment: Can you add some example code for better understanding

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).